# how to set the empty tag in generating xml from oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
SET PAGES 0;
SET LINE 1000;
SET LONG 9999999;
SPOOL C:\pensionnew.xml;
col foo format a60000
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT * FROM DATAAG')foo FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF;
```

i use this code for generating xml.. the answer is:suppose the the column not have value means the tag wont came . i need empty tag for that for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1014818) for it, dont use the quick fire `getxml(string)` version.

eg:

```
SQL> variable xml clob;
SQL> declare
  2    ctx number;
  3  begin
  4    dbms_lob.createtemporary(:xml, true, dbms_lob.call);
  5    ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext('select * from foo');
  6    dbms_xmlgen.setnullhandling(ctx, dbms_xmlgen.EMPTY_TAG);
  7    dbms_xmlgen.getxml(ctx, :xml);
  8    dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(ctx);
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print xml

XML
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <A>a</A>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <A/>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: ya its working fine .. but how to save this xml file  in my system

Comment: @user1999281 the same as you did with spool etc should be fine (you may want to do other stuff like set heading off , echo off, feedback off etc to supress the other output